# How Do I Place a Image or text in a certain part of the screen

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="style-strip-holder">
        <span id="logo">SMLCA</span>
        <div id="colorstrip"/>
        <div id="logo">
             <img src="//images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5dd524d14eb1de01971d3330/1574251666169-X1OWTE0W6M3X8ZZJJE4B/SMLCA-web-title.png?format=140w" align="top_left">
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        <header class="grey-header">
            <style>
                #colorstrip{
                    width: 100%; height: 100px;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
                    background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
                }
            </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I have somehow found out how to put a colored strip in my code with HTMl & css. I have text and a image I am going to try to put on the colored strip, the only way I can think of doing that is by putting it in a certain area (with pixels like x=100 y=250). I have tried and it is at the top but i don't know if i can get that image any more centered and i have no idea where to start with the text.

P.S. This is my first time using Stack overflow for asking questions

Comment: Please show your code , also , you are not clear enough... it seems what you are talking about is adding css to your code but without knowing what is your output even has any html in it... I can't really help...

Comment: Ok, thank you i am very new i don't know what people need

Comment: So where do you want the text and the image to be ? right now the image is at the top and above it the text lies. what should be moved where? :)

Comment: In the grey strip if you would like to know what i am going for go to smlca.org

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the background-image css sprite and positioning just for the example :

```css
#colorstrip{
            position: absolute;
            top: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
            text-align: center;
            background-position-x: 250px;
            background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
            background-image: url(//images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5dd524d14eb1de01971d3330/1574251666169-X1OWTE0W6M3X8ZZJJE4B/SMLCA-web-title.png?format=140w);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="style-strip-holder">

        <div id="colorstrip"/>
            <span id="logo">SMLCA</span>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

You can see there are two elements in play here: the background-image - background-position etc... and the position of the div itself and it's top etc....

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using margins to position the image and text where you want them, and setting the `position: absolute`. this is all in CSS.

Comment: What would i put it in? (like .div{} or .body{})

Comment: ideally a `<div></div>`.

Comment: So            <div>              position: absolute:        </div>     just with new line between div position and endline?

Comment: yes and add margins to position it as needed (position: absolute should be in the styles for that div)